# Regex: limited symbols between square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

String sample: `Text sample [79zd915j][fxC1bPYW][asd12233]`

As result I want to have an array: `["[79bl9F5j]", "[fKCebPYW]", "[asd12233]"]`

I made solution, but somehow in doesn't stop after 8 symbols inside brackets and goes to the end of string.

My regex: `/(\[[\w\d]{8}\])+/.exec("Text sample [79bl9F5j][fKCebPYW][asd12233]")`

My result: `["[79bl9F5j][fKCebPYW][asd12233]", "[asd12233]"]`

Help me to write correct one and tell me please what is wrong with my regex? Why it doesn't work like I expected?

Comment: `\w` is the predefined `[A-Za-z0-9_]` which already includes `\d` = `[0-9]` so you don't need both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR → use `String.match()` instead of `RegExp.exec()`

---

Your pattern `/(\[[\w\d]{8}\])+/` can be simplified first, because the pre-defined `\w` is `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and that already contains everything in `\d` - so we simplify to `/(\[\w{8)\])+/`

Your use of `+` means match one-or-more so this means match `[12345678]` as many times as it occurs, and return *that*, which is why you get `"[79bl9F5j][fKCebPYW][asd12233]"` as your first result.

The `.exec()` method returns an array containing the whole match as `result[0]` followed by each capturing group in subsequent array elements. See [the MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Return_value) for exec.

Your second array element is, therefore, the *captured group*, not repeated matches.

You want a *global* match because you want to find *all* occurrences of `[12345678]` so eliminate the `+` and add the `g` switch, which now gives a regex of `/(\[\w{8)\])/g`

Let's assign that to a var so we don't have to keep retyping it:
`> var re = /(\[\w{8)\])/g;`

`.exec()` gives you the *first* match when you run it:

```
> re.exec("Text sample [79bl9F5j][fKCebPYW][asd12233]");
["[79bl9F5j]", "[79bl9F5j]"]
```

but with a global match you can run it again (and again)

```
> re.exec("Text sample [79bl9F5j][fKCebPYW][asd12233]");
["[fKCebPYW]", "[fKCebPYW]"]
```

See this time it returns the *second* match.  But it's returning each one twice... that's because of the capturing group.  Let's drop that part and redefine our re then run the .exec...

```
> var re = /\[\w{8}\]/g;
undefined
> re.exec("Text sample [79bl9F5j][fKCebPYW][asd12233]");
["[79bl9F5j]"]
> re.exec("Text sample [79bl9F5j][fKCebPYW][asd12233]");
["[fKCebPYW]"]
> re.exec("Text sample [79bl9F5j][fKCebPYW][asd12233]");
["[asd12233]"]
```

So, you can get all matches by running `.exec()` in a loop, re-using the regular expression on the same string, because the regexp object remembers the context.

**But** it's much easier than that — because instead of using `RegExp.exec()` you can [`String.match(regexp)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) which returns "An Array containing the entire match result..."

```
> var re = /\[\w{8}\]/g;
undefined
> "Text sample [79bl9F5j][fKCebPYW][asd12233]".match(re);
["[79bl9F5j]", "[fKCebPYW]", "[asd12233]"]
> "Text sample [79bl9F5j] x [fKCebPYW][asd12233]    [1234efgh]".match(re);
["[79bl9F5j]", "[fKCebPYW]", "[asd12233]", "[1234efgh]"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(\[\w{8}\])
```

is enough.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/xvY9D9/1

the `+` sign is causing the trouble.It will match the whole `[79zd915j][fxC1bPYW][asd12233]` but capture only the last `[asd12233]` in group 1 as regex engine remembers only the last group when consecutive groups are being matched

Answer (score 1):

The first *problem* is `+` . That means a repeat of **one** ore **more times** from what is before. So this would match:

`[abcdefgh]` and `[abcdefgh][abcdefgh]` and `[abcdefgh][abcdefgh][abcdefgh]`...

**For example**

```js
var str = "Text sample [79zd915j][fxC1bPYW]xxx[asd12233]";
var regex = /(\[[\w\d]{8}\])+/;
var res = regex.exec(str);

console.log(res[0]);
```

But you won't match it together, you want match it **separate**!

The second *problem* is that `exec()` even with a global flag
will output **only** the **first occurrence**:

```js
var str = "Text sample [79zd915j][fxC1bPYW]xxx[asd12233]";
var regex = /(\[[\w\d]{8}\])/g;
var res = regex.exec(str);

console.log(res[0]);
```

So in this case use [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) without a `+` and with a global flag:

```js
var str = "Text sample [79zd915j][fxC1bPYW]xxx[asd12233]";
var regex = /(\[[\w\d]{8}\])/g;
var res = str.match(regex);

console.log(res);
```

More information about [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).